# Keras multi-step LSTM batch train classification at each step

Tags: python, keras, time-series, classification, lstm

**Question**

How to batch train a multi-step LSTM in Keras for single-label multi-class classificaiton, at each time-step for > 2 classes?

**Current Error**

Each target batch is a 3-dimensional array with shape `(batch_size, n_time_steps, n_classes)` but Keras expects a 2-dimensional array.

**Example/Context**

Suppose we have daily closing prices for N stocks and for each day and stock: m features and one of three actions "bought", "held", "sold".
If there are 30 days' worth of data per stock we may train an LSTM to predict each action (on each day, for each stock) as follows.

For each batch of samples of size n << N, `X_train` will have a shape of `(n, 30, m)` i.e. `n` samples, 30 time-steps, and `m` features. After one-hot encoding "bought", "held", and "sold" `Y_train` will have a shape of `(n, 30, 3)`, which is an array of 3-dimensions.

The problem is that Keras is giving an error due to expecting `Y_train` to be 2-dimensional.

Here is a code snippet:

```
n_time_steps = 30
n_ftrs = 700
n_neurons = 100
n_classes = 3
batch_size = 256
n_epochs = 500
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_neurons, input_shape=(n_time_steps, n_ftrs)))
model.add(Dense(n_classes, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', 
    metrics=['accuracy'])

for e in range(n_epochs):
  X_train, Y_train = BatchGenerator()
  # Y_train.shape = (256, 30, 3)
  model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=1)
```

**Error**

```
Error when checking target: expected dense_20 to have 2 dimensions, 
but got array with shape (256, 30, 3)
```

Comment: Can you try setting the input shape to first LSTM like `(None, n_time_steps, n_ftrs)` without setting `return_sequences` to `True`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add change your LSTM layer like so:

```
model.add(LSTM(n_neurons, input_shape=(n_time_steps, n_ftrs), return_sequences=True))
```

This argument does the following:

> return_sequences: Boolean. Whether to return the last output in the output sequence, or the full sequence.

I'm going to be completely honest and say im not sure why it is like this, my LSTM is a bit rusty, as i would believe it should be the other way around, but im able to get your code running like this. If someone would like to clarify why this works that would be great.

Comment: thank you. the documentation on return_sequences could be a bit clearer, e.g. would it be accurate to simply state: "return_sequences: Boolean. If True, returns the last output in the output sequence. If false, returns the full sequence" ?

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the `model.summary()` output you would realize what the problem is:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 100)               320400    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_74 (Dense)             (None, 3)                 303       
=================================================================
Total params: 320,703
Trainable params: 320,703
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

As you can see the output shape of `LSTM` layer is `(None, 100)` which means that **only the output of last timestep is returned**. And as a result, the output shape of `Dense` layer is `(None, 3)` which means that it would classify the whole input timeseries (i.e. the whole 30-day data of a stock) in to one of 3 classes. This is not what you want. Rather you want to classify each timestep of the input timeseries. To make this happen, as @VegardKT suggested, you can pass `return_sequences=True` to the `LSTM` layer to have its output at each timestep. Let's look at the `model.summary()` output after this change:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 30, 100)           320400    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_75 (Dense)             (None, 30, 3)             303       
=================================================================
Total params: 320,703
Trainable params: 320,703
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

​As you can see, now the `LSTM` layer gives the output of each timestep and therefore the `Dense` layer which acts a classifier would be able to classify each of those timesteps into one of 3 classes as desired.

Comment: insightful comment explaining more of what's going on with return_sequences=True. thank you.

Comment: Good explenation, thank you @today
Would it not make more sense if they had reversed the boolean for return_Sequences still though?

Comment: @VegardKT Well, I think the otherwise. I look at this way: "return output sequences". So it clearly makes sense that when "return_sequences=True" it means that all the timestep outputs (i.e. output sequence) should be returned (and not only the output of last timestep). I edited my answer and made this more clear.